# Deleted cron jobs still running on wordpress website

Tags: linux, wordpress, cron, cpanel

I have created some cron jobs in cpanel and deleted. But some of them are still running.
How can I find where these are stored and delete them?
Can I use Cpanel terminal for this?

Or in which files or database table could they be stored so that I can delete them from there?

Answer (score 0):

With the following command, you can see the list of crons and the items that do not have #(comment) will be executed.

`run with the root user or the user you use`

```
 crontab -e
```

Comment: Thank you,, but this only returns the cron jobs that I can already see in the Cpanel->Cron jobs, the ones I need. It does not show the cron jobs that were deleted but still running.

Answer (score 0):

if you have access to Cpanel terminal as a non-root user. at first find the `pid` of your processes and then kill them.

```
ps -aux | grep ProcessName
```

for example if your process related to python or java write them.

```
kill -9 pid
```

now kill your proccess.

for finding `pid` of your process also you can use `top` command and then type `c` from your keyboard and then find your process.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not list any cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your WordPress db
Login into PHPMyAdmin and select your WordPress database
The wp_options table record that storages cron data (option_name = ‘cron’) in the database and the cron job has disappeared.

Regards

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I already checked the "Cron"  option in "WP-options" table,, the deleted cron jobs are not in there either,, I can see them running on the plugin I use, WP All import,,(the cron jobs are configured to run an import) and also in cpanel->vistors.